# How to restrict user from double clicking any command button

Tags: c#, winforms, silverlight

There is an issue that I am facing, is to restrict user from double clicking on a command button. What it does is execute twice the code written inside it's click event. I've read many solutions for it, which I find are irrelevant. The command button, they say, should be disable after a click is performed so that user won't be able to perform another click. This will create an issue when an error occur and the code that is written to enable the button didn't execute.

Is there any other way to do it? Please suggest if any one have better option than this.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: How about re-enabling the button in a finally statement or similar?

Comment: Soner: Yup I already had tried a lot of things to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You could disable it, and put all your code within a `try`, `catch`, `finally` clause, and put the enabling code in `finally`.

[Give it a read.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dszsf989%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

That way it should always run, exception or not.

Comment: No this isn't the best way, try catch block increases the line of compiled code and thereby increases the processing time for the code execution. If number of buttons increases to a lot, the processing time will increases to a hell lot.

Comment: Are you going to run the code on hardware from the 1980's? If not, it's really not a problem.

Comment: Regardless of the performance overhead, it doesn't work if you disable it using CanExecute. It doesn't get checked until your Execute is done.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are referring to WPF, as Windows Forms has a specific double click event which can be disregarded.

Unfortunately WPF does not make a distinction between double clicking a button and clicking the button twice. This means that you have to perform the check to see if the second click occurred too soon to the first click to be regarded.

This could be done by storing the DateTime.Now in a member variable in the button click event handler and if the click occurs within a too short amount of time of the previous click, simply indicate that the button click event was handled and return without doing anything.

Comment: Yes Mort it seems to be a good idea. But I have already tried implementing it. It takes a lot of code to write in order to check double clicking. In my application, since I have lots of buttons, it will just increase the line of codes and nothing else.